# Python 3 setter version of getargspec? Or other way to dynamically create named arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, introspection

I happen to have some code which uses introspection to learn what the arguments of a function are, and then does some logic based on what these names are. So for example, I might create some functions like

```
def func1(a,b):
    return a+b

def func2(a):
    return a

def func3(b):
    return b
```

and by using e.g. `inspect.getargspec(func1)` I can get the list ["a","b"] returned. In this way the code I have can check if some functions have the same argument names.

So now, I want to create a bunch of functions dynamically, with say another function. Schematically I want to do e.g.

```
def make_funcs():
    func_list = []
    for i in 10:
        def f(x_i): ***here x_i should be x_1, or x_2, etc.
            return x_i:
        func_list += [f]
    return func_list
```

where, "x_i" should actually be x_1, x_2, etc. So that when I inspect these functions with `getargspec` the result is "x_1", "x_2", etc. It would also be acceptable to somehow set the argument names after the function is created. So for example I could create the functions with a generic argument name and then change it later to the specific names needed.

Is there some way to do either of these things?

Comment: `getargspec` does not create arguments. Your question is a bit unclear - post a minimal snippets of exactly what you want to do, and mark the line of pseudo code you're asking about.

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't create arguments. It gets them. I am trying to create the functions such that getargspec returns the result I indicated in the question. I have marked the line of pseudocode that I want to control better.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `**kwargs` as parameter, so parameter names are not set on function definition but can be retrieved from dict `kwargs`?

Btw, you should provide an example, because I don't clearly get the point of a function that could not rely on the name of its parameter to work ;)

Comment: The actual code that does the introspection is not particularly simple or relevant to the question so I am not sure it helps to post it. But it is part of an optimisation routine, where I am minimising a product of function. If the parameters for these functions are independent then I can minimise each component of the product independently, but otherwise I must do a larger-dimension minimisation. So I need to know which of the functions require the same arguments and which are independent. Thus using **kwargs is no good since then the dependency structure is hidden.

Comment: Ok, so basically, the idea is to define a new function at runtime, whose parameter lists is not fixed yet, and its code neither, right?

Comment: Well the code can be fixed, that's no problem. In fact these functions will all be identical, but I need the arguments to be named differently. Otherwise yes that's the idea.

Comment: I don't know if this is achievable. One (ugly!) possibility would be to write function as a string, and then use `eval` to create that function.

Comment: Haha, yeah I thought about that, but I thought I would check first if there was a better way...

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change how `inspect.getargspec` reads the function's signature, you can hand-craft a [`inspect.Signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature) object and assign it to the function's `__signature__` attribute:

```
import inspect

def f(x_i):
    return x_i

i = 0
param = inspect.Parameter('x_{}'.format(i), inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY)
f.__signature__ = inspect.Signature([param])
```

(See also the documentation of the [`inspect.Parameter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) constructor.)

Setting the signature like this interacts correctly with [`inspect.getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec) (the not-deprecated version of [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec)) and [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature):

```
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(f)
FullArgSpec(args=['x_0'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None,
            kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

However, it does not actually change the name of the parameter, so keyword arguments don't work correctly:

```
>>> f(x_0=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x_0'
>>> f(x_i=3)
3
```

If you need keyword arguments to work correctly, the easiest solution is to create the function dynamically with [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```
i = 0

globs = {}
code = """
def f(x_{0}):
    return x_{0}
""".format(i)
exec(code, globs)
f = globs['f']
```

```
>>> f(3)
3
>>> f(x_0=3)
3
```

Comment: Ahh, so close. I do actually need the keyword arguments to work correctly, half the point of introspecting for these argument names is to know what keyword arguments to use for them.

Comment: Haha ok, I tried to avoid it, but alright, exec it is.